# What is the classification of (3, 4)-pseudoriemannian manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Have mathematicians found a comprehensive list of all pseudoriemannian manifolds with 3 spacelike and 4 timelike dimensions up to diffeomorphism?

Comment: I don't think such a classification exists, but there are many. For example, the product of any four-manifold with any three-manifold. There are also non-products, such as $S^7$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese does $S^7$ have four timelike dimensions and three spacelike dimensions?

Comment: @TomislavOstojich: The point is that $S^7$ is a parallelizable manifold (its tangent bundle is trivial). Every parallelizable $n$-dimensional manifold admits a pseudo-Riemannian metric of any signature $(p,q)$ with $p+q=n$. One can also prove that for every finitely presented group $G$ there exists a compact pseudo-Riemannian $(3,4)$-manifold with fundamental group isomorphic to $G$. Hence, a meaningful classification is impossible.

Comment: @MoisheCohen is $S^7$ with a pseudoriemannian metric an exotic sphere?

Comment: @TomislavOstojich: If you want so, you can use an exotic sphere. But you can also take it to be the standard sphere. Both are parallelizable, this is all what you need.

Comment: @MoisheCohen thank you for the information. I think the answer to the question "Is $S^7 with a pseudoriemannian metric an exotic sphere?" is no.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich: The notion of an exotic sphere has nothing to do with a metric, it depends only on the smooth structure of the manifold. If $M$ is an n-dimensional manifold homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to the standard n-sphere, then $M$ is called an exotic sphere.